# Python main script not waiting for user response in Tkinter GUI

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

I am brand new to using the Tkinter GUI and stuck while trying to make an interactive program that 1) solicits feedback from the user in the GUI, 2) waits for the user to respond and hit enter and 3) then uses the input to inform the next steps in the main script.

However, I am unable to make step 2 execute properly.  At the function call waitforinput(), I would expect the main script to wait before moving on to the next lines which are test printouts.  Instead, it prints the main script test lines with '' for result and then places an entry box that works.  Why is this program moving to the next line before the waitforinput function is completed?  Thanks!

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import threading, time

# assignments for input thread
WAIT_DELAY = 250 #milliseconds
lock = threading.Lock()  # Lock for shared resources.
finished = False
result = ''

# Set up the graphical interface
root = tk.Tk(className='My Flashcards')

def main():    
    # request and wait for input from user 
    waitforinput()
    Test = tk.Label(root, text = "result = " + result)
    Test.pack()
    Test.config(font = ('verdana', 24), bg ='#BE9CCA')

# sets background thread for getinput from user
def waitforinput():
    global finished
    with lock:
        finished = False
    t = threading.Thread(target=getinput)
    t.daemon = True
    root.after(WAIT_DELAY, check_status) # start waiting
    t.start()

# checks to see if user has inputted
def check_status():
    with lock:
        if not finished: 
            root.after(WAIT_DELAY, check_status) # keep waiting

# solicits and returns a string from the user
def getinput():
    
    # declaring string variable for storing name and password 
    answer_var = tk.StringVar()
        
    # define a function that will get the answer and return it
    def user_response(event = None):
        answer = answer_entry.get()
        global result
        result = answer
        global finished 
        finished = True # to break out of loop
    
    # creating an entry for inputting answer using widget Entry
    answer_entry = tk.Entry(root, width = 1, borderwidth = 5, bg ='#BE9CCA', textvariable = answer_var) ## could be global with args
    
    # making it so that enter calls function
    answer_entry.bind('<Return>', user_response)   

    # placing the entry 
    answer_entry.pack()
    answer_entry.focus()

main()
root.mainloop()
'''
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use threads to wait for a response. Tkinter has methods specifically for waiting: `wait_window` and `wait_variable`.

`wait_window` waits for a window to be destroyed. This is typically used when creating a modal dialog. `wait_variable` can be used to wait until one of the special tkinter variable objects has been modified.

If you want your code to wait until a user has pressed the enter key in an entry, you can set a binding on that key to set a variable, and then wait for that variable to be set. Note: you normally don't want to use `wait_variable` for a variable used as the value of `textvariable` since the wait will stop as soon as a single character has been entered.

Your `getinput` function could look something like this, which can be called directly without the use of threads:

```
def getinput():

    answer_var = tk.StringVar()
    def user_response(event):
        answer_var.set(answer_entry.get())
        return

    answer_entry = tk.Entry(root, width = 1, borderwidth = 5, bg ='#BE9CCA')
    answer_entry.bind('<Return>', user_response)
    answer_entry.pack()
    answer_entry.focus()

    answer_entry.wait_variable(answer_var)
    return answer_var.get()
```

Once the statement `answer_entry.wait_variable(answer_var)` executes, tkinter will enter an event loop and won't return until `answer_var` has been set. You can then call `get` on the variable and return the value.

Here is how you can modify your `main` function to call this function:

```
def main():
    result = getinput()
    Test = tk.Label(root, text = "result = " + result)
    Test.pack()
    Test.config(font = ('verdana', 24), bg ='#BE9CCA')
```

Comment: This is great - I am one step closer to success.  However, like you mentioned, it is returning when I type the first letter, not waiting for enter.  Is there a fix for that?  A way to tie wait to enter?

Comment: @DavidGallagher: I addressed that problem in my answer.

Comment: You are right.  When I copied your code in, everything worked perfectly.  I had a split screen mode and didn't see (and therefore didn't delete) the textvariable portion.  My mistake.  Thanks again!